# CodeIgniter and custom routes

Tags: codeigniter, content-management-system, routes, theory

I am interested in a theoretical question. For example, I want to create CMS with readable URL (for example, /hot-news/very-hot-news/). I do not want to break the object-oriented model of the engine, so I plan to create a route file that will be rewriting from the administration panel every time, when I add new article.

If my project grow to, for example, 10,000 of these URLs, it will not be an extra load, because route engine - an array that keeps all records. Yes, I want to use regular expressions for some sections, but in theory it could be at the root of 10,000 pages with different controllers (/my-gallery/ → /gallery/$1, /feedback/ → /feedback/, etc).

Show you how to properly in CodeIgniter add full support for URL-read and whether I want to build my system?

Comment: could you possibly rephrase your last sentence? I read it 4 times and I still cant understand what you're trying to ask

Comment: @HeHui I want to build CMS with URL-readable support (for ex. /users-articles/cats-want-to-eat/). I know only 2 ways to do this: 1) use routes 2) rewrite all request to one controller, which will select from DB type of requested page and call model. Maybe there are more than 2 ways?